# Custom sql query in my existing ZF2 (Zend Framework 2) entity

Tags: php, jquery, database, zend-framework2

I have a class that already previously had a simple fetchAll() method. I got it from the ZF2 tutorial and it uses ResultSet and TableGateway. Only now I want it to take an argument that I can check for so that if a customer ID is passed, it will only return the rows with that customer ID.

This is what the method looks like:

```
public function fetchAll($CCID = null)
{
    if($CCID == null){
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
        return $resultSet;
    } else {
        // Same as above, only where customerId = $CCID
        return $resultSet;
    }
}
```

I've tried this (adding use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql:

```
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select->where(array('customerId' => $CCID));
```

This was pretty much a complete guess, but I tried it because it looked like it made sense. In my Module file the TableGateway factory looks like this:

```
     'JobsTableGateway' => function($sm){
          $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
          $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
          $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Job());
          return new TableGateway('runningjobs', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
      },
```

Does anyone know how to basically do the standard fetchAll() like in the first part of the conditional except with a 'where' part? Or maybe there's a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the docs:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html

> public function select($where = null);

So it should be something like this:

```
$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(array('customerId' => $CCID));
```

Comment: Cheers, that worked! Had read them but completely missed that. I'm still fairly new to working with frameworks so reading all the docs can be overwhelming sometimes.